# can't add new clients to OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I've got an ovpn server set up with various clients which all seem to be working well up to now. I'm now trying to add additional clients.

My procedure was the following:

1. Close OVPN
2. In admin cmd:   -vars build-key new_client
3. Created new client files successfully.
4. Copied CA, cert, and key files from easy-rsa\keys folder and uploaded to client machine.
5. Created new client config file in config\ccd folder (exact same as other working client files but with new client CN and IP's)
6. Started OVPN

So this obviously didn't work. The new client can't connect.
In the log, the ifconfig pool list does not contain the new client names.

The old clients work fine.

So my question is what am I missing, do I need to replace the old CA and df files in config folder? Or something else?

Comment: How does the final client config file represent? Do all keys are embedded in the config file or are they have relative paths instead?

Comment: And why not use username and password authentication with CA and DF. That way you save a lot of hassle when you need to remove a client. At the moment if you need to remove a single user, you'll have to generate new CA and DF, result in replacing every single client that used previous CA & DF with the new once.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly sure what you mean in the first comment. Are you asking to see the config file ? The keys are saved in the easy-rsa/keys folder, they are not in the config file as far as I'm aware

Comment: Are your CA and HMAC embedded in the client config file or are they referred by relative path?

Comment: Hmm, so in the config folder I have the CA, dh , and server config file ( which referes to the CA and dh files. Within that folder there is ther ccd folder which contain the client config file which simply contains :
ifconfig-push ...
iroute...
push route...

Comment: So your Client config file also needs to have the CA and HMAC as well as the server. You can either have it embedded in the client config file or relative path. Here's Doc reference I created for myself. https://github.com/praveenprem/Docs/blob/master/OpenVPN.md

Comment: Hmm ok , don't support you have document for windows server instead ?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I don't. It should be same regardless